# Getting strings from i18n YAML file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, yaml

I have some view code:

```
<span data-something="[<%= t('.asd') %>, <%= t('.dsf') %>]></span>
```

I use this code to get some dynamic strings translated into the view. My YAML is something like:

```
en:
  feature:
    asd: "Asdddd"
    dsf: "adasdsadasda"
```

Is there a way I can use to dynamically get all the "features" from the YAML by locale and put it in the data-attribute?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is pretty simple to do:

```
I18n.translate('feature').values.join(', ')
```

You'll end up with a string `"Asdddd, adasdsadasda"`.

Comment: Also, I much prefer explicitly writing out I18n.translate as opposed to the t helper as its much easier to search through your project to find all the translations.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's as easy as `t('feature')` to get the hash, you might want to just have the values so could you try `t('feature').keys`?